# Moving a div element with JQuery addClass()/removeClass/() method

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I wish to move a div block element adding and removing a class if the user scroll down.
I plan to add/remove a class when this JQuery function is executed:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {

h = $(window).height();
w = $(window).width();

//jQuery to collapse the navbar on scroll
if ($(".navbar").offset().top > 50) {
    $('.loaded #loader-wrapper .loader-section.section-top').removeClass('.loaded #loader-wrapper .loader-section.section-top ');
    $('.loaded #loader-wrapper .loader-section.section-top').addClass('.loaded #loader-wrapper .loader-section.section-top-collapsed ');    
} else {
    // $(".navbar-fixed-top").removeClass("top-nav-collapse");
    $('.loaded #loader-wrapper .loader-section.section-top').removeClass('.loaded #loader-wrapper .loader-section.section-top-collapsed ');
    $('.loaded #loader-wrapper .loader-section.section-top').addClass('.loaded #loader-wrapper .loader-section.section-top ');
}});
```

Precisely I wrote the class `.loader-section.section-top` in this way:

```
#loader-wrapper .loader-section.section-top {
display:flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
top:0;
height: 50%;
background:url('../img/thewall.jpg');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: 0 20%;
text-align: center;

display:flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;

-webkit-box-shadow: 2px 6px 11px -1px rgba(0,0,0,0.31);
-moz-box-shadow: 2px 6px 11px -1px rgba(0,0,0,0.31);
box-shadow: 2px 6px 11px -1px rgba(0,0,0,0.31);
```

}

When a user open my website, a panel slide up with CSS transform, that is in this class:

```
.loaded #loader-wrapper .loader-section.section-top {
-webkit-transform: translateY(-78%);  /* Chrome, Opera 15+, Safari 3.1+ */
    -ms-transform: translateY(-78%);  /* IE 9 */
        transform: translateY(-78%);  /* Firefox 16+, IE 10+, Opera */

-webkit-transition: all 1.5s 1s cubic-bezier(0.645, 0.045, 0.355, 1.000);  
        transition: all 1.5s 1s cubic-bezier(0.645, 0.045, 0.355, 1.000);
```

}

Once it has been loaded and user scroll down, I wish moving a little bit the panel, so I wrote this other class:

```
.loaded #loader-wrapper .loader-section.section-top-collapsed {
-webkit-transform: translateY(-80%);  /* Chrome, Opera 15+, Safari 3.1+ */
    -ms-transform: translateY(-80%);  /* IE 9 */
        transform: translateY(-80%);  /* Firefox 16+, IE 10+, Opera */

-webkit-transition: all 1.5s 1s cubic-bezier(0.645, 0.045, 0.355, 1.000);  
        transition: all 1.5s 1s cubic-bezier(0.645, 0.045, 0.355, 1.000);
```

}

As shown by the code I remove the class `.loaded #loader-wrapper .loader-section.section-top` and add the class `.loaded #loader-wrapper .loader-section.section-top-collapsed`, and do the opposite when user slide up to the top.

Here the html code:

```
<div id="loader-wrapper"> 

 ... Main site ...

 <div class="loader-section section-top">

        ... navbar content and other things...

  </div>

  <div class="loader-section section-bottom">

        ...other things...

  </div>
</div>
```

and some useful information on how these elements are styled:

```
#loader-wrapper {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
z-index: 1000;  }



#loader-wrapper .loader-section {
position: fixed;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
z-index: 1001;
```

}

Unfortunately nothing moves, using Chrome developer tools I see, however, that the classes are properly settled on, why not move?

I forgot, I'm using JQuery and Bootstrap 3 v1.11.3

Comment: addClass and removeClass does not require `.` before class name.

Comment: Right, I modified all the class name and fixed JQuery instruction. Now is ok! Thanks